# slicing python list beyond its length

Tags: python, list, numpy, slice, numpy-slicing

I have to slice a Python list/numpy array from an index to -dx and +dx.
where dx is constant. for example:
(the position/index that contains 1 only for illustration, as the center index).

```
A = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
dx=3
print(A[4-dx: 4+dx+1])  # 4 is the position of '1'

>>>[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

But for this case,

```
B = [0, 1, 0, 0, 0 ,0, 0 ,0, 0]
print(B[1-dx: 1+dx+1])
>>>[]  # because 1-dx <0.
```

but what i need from case B is `[0, 1, 0, 0, 0]`

so i did something like this, to prevent empty list/array, say `n` is the center index:

```
if n-dx <0:
    result= B[:n+dx+1]
```

Although the above method works fine.
The original code is quite complicated, and I have to put this `if...#complicated version#` everywhere.

Is there any other way around? Maybe I miss something.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `max()` function to bound the index at `0`.

```
print(A[max(0,4-dx): 4+dx+1])
```

Comment: thanks for quick response. Yes it works, and I'm out of repeating 'if-else' hell.